# Apache2 Virtual Host 1 file for any URL

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, ubuntu-12.04, url

I have an Apache2 Virtual host set up to pick up access from any URL (dns) other than the ones I have set up.

Basically I want any access to this to show a page (index.html) but keep the URL the user visited in their address bar.

E.G.

User visits `example.url.com/example.php?param=text`

or they go to `anysubdomain.example.com/anything`

or to `subdomain.anotherurl.com/`

then they will see the file `index.html` but their address bar would still be on `example.url.com/example.php?param=text` (or wherever they went)

Output of `apache2ctl -S`

`apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and default servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
         port 80 namevhost 127.0.1.1 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
Syntax OK`

Help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to write a Rewrite URL and place it either in the .htaccess in the document root of your default vhost or the configuration of your default vhost.

I have currently no server at hand to test, but it should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ! "%{REQUEST_URI}" = <path to your file which should be displayed>
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) <path to your file which should be displayed> [P]
```

You need the modules mod_proxy and mod_rewrite for this to work!
Further details can be found at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [flag p](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p).